# Plotting multiple lines from multiple data frames

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I'm a very beginner to R. So I have 2 data files, A.dat and B.dat like:

```
1   101203
2   3231233  
3   213213
...
```

So I did

```
A <- read.table("A.dat", col.names = c("time","power"))
B <- read.table("B.dat", col.names = c("time","power"))
```

And I want to do line plot for A and B in the same system (Sorry, i can't upload image yet). Any suggestions on how to go about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using `ggplot2` (package can be downloaded from CRAN). This first requires a little data processing:

```
A$group = "A"
B$group = "B"
dat = rbind(A,B)
```

and then plotting the figure:

```
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = power, color = group), data = dat) + geom_line()
```

For base graphics, something like this should work:

```
plot(power~time, A)
lines(power~time, B)
```

Comment: Just curious, did you pick the plot solution.